# Best way to share an Azure Storage Container with multiple users within an organization

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement of allowing organization level access to one of my storage containers within Azure.
What would be the best way to go about with this?

The access is being implemented via bash script.

Answer (score 1):

1, Create a group and contains the users.

[image]

[image]

[image]

2, After created the group, go to the 'Access Control' of your container, then allow the group you created just now to access.

[image]

[image]

(Make sure these users don't have access in storage account level. Otherwise they will be able to access the container at the beginning.)